# testing significance of random effects

Tags: mixed-model, anova, multilevel-analysis

I have a random effects model and I want to test whether they are significant or not. I'm using statsmodels.formula.api. I read I need to test whether the variance for a parameter is 0, but can't perform a t-test, and the ANOVA test in statsmodel does not support mixed effects models. How should I test them then?

Comment: You could look at [Wald tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test), [score tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_test), and [likelihood-ratio tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test). I'm not saying they're appropriate for your problem, but I would look at them further to see if they apply.

Comment: What are the random effects? Why do you want to test them?